# Need to target item only inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, target

Right now I have .clrChart hidden and want to unhide with click on .color but have multiple of these in a row so I need to target the one under the click.

```
<div class="color">
    <a><img src="img/clrBttn.png" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/clrChart2.jpg" alt="color chart" class="clrChart" /></a>
</div>
```

I have tried this w/ no avail.

```
$('.color').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.clrChart').show();
        });
```

any help would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: `$('.clrChart', this).show()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `.find()` instead of `.next()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.color').click(function() {
   $(this).find('.clrChart').show();
});
```

This will find a descendant inside the current .color